# How to map keyboard keys in c#

Tags: c#, keyboard, mapping, keyboard-events

I'm trying to map some keys in the keyboard to another keys..e.g: lets say I want to use WSAD instead of the Up, Down, Left, Right arrows so whenever W is pressed the cursor goes up in Notepad for instance and so on for the rest ?

I also need this mapping to happen even when the form is out of focus.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the KeyPress events for detecting key presses and then do what ever you want to do when those events are fired...

Code for normal key detection:

```
yourControl.KeyPress += passwordString_KeyPress; // in Form load 

private void yourControl_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == (char)(Keys.Enter))
    {
        // your code here when the Enter key is pressed
    }
}
```

Now You want global key detection i.e you want to detect keys even when the form is not active or in focus you should take a look [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/globalhook.aspx) or [here](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/180436-global-hotkeys/).

Both the links are tutorial for global key detection...